# Assistance with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table that I import into excel... What I am needing to do is loop through the names (i.e. Emp1). For every instance of that employee, I need to copy columns C through F and paste in another worksheet. I would like for this to happen with every employee on the sheet.

```
Sub DiscrepFormReport()
    Dim cell As Range

    Range("A1").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Range("A1") = Sheets("RawData").range("B2))

    For Each cell In Range("B2:B200")
        If cell <> "" Then
            Sheets("RawData").Range("C2:F2").Copy
            Sheets("DiscrepencyForm").Range("C2:F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: This code says "Copy C2:F2 from RawData onto DiscrepancyForm  and do it 199 times". I am not understanding the purpose of doing it after the first time. The data is already copied, why do it 198 more times?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` has no interaction with `cell` and is not related to the other two lines in the loop either.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the idea, you'd want something like:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Const STARTING_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim c As Long: c = STARTING_ROW

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Sheets("RawData").Range("B2:B200").Cells
        If cell <> "" Then
            Sheets("DiscrepencyForm").Range("C:F").Rows(c).Value = cell.EntireRow.Columns(3).Resize(, 4).Value
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

You can avoid `.Copy` since you're specifying that you only want values. You can just directly assign the values on the range objects, which skips the use of the windows clipboard and saves a lot of time. No need for `Select` or `Activecell`. All we need is to use the `cell` loop element and a second index, `c`, to track the destination range on the other sheet.

Answer (score 1):

### Group Data Using a Dictionary of Collections

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateDiscrepencyReport()
    
    ' 1. Define constants.
    
    ' s - Source (read from)
    Const sName As String = "RawData"
    Const sCriteriaRangeAddress As String = "B2:B200"
    Const sCopyColumns As String = "C:F"
    ' d - Destination (write to)
    Const dName As String = "DiscrepencyForm"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "C2"
    
    ' 2. Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' 3. Write the source criteria data to an array.
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    ' Reference the source criteria range ('srg').
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sCriteriaRangeAddress)
    ' Write the values from the source criteria (one-column) range
    ' to a 2D one-based (one-column) array ('sData')...
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    ' ... and write its number of rows to a variable ('srCount').
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    
    ' 4. Write the unique source criteria data to a dictionary.
    '    In the dictionary, its 'keys' ('sKey') will hold the unique values,
    '    while each of the corresponding 'items' ('dict(sKey)') will hold
    '    a collection of the array rows ('sr') in which the 'key' appears.
    '    Also, the number of destination rows ('drCount') will be determined.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sKey As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim drCount As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sKey = sData(sr, 1)
        If Not IsError(sKey) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(CStr(sKey)) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
                    ' Add the key and assign its item a new collection.
                    Set dict(sKey) = New Collection
                'Else ' key exist; collection already assigned; do nothing
                End If
                dict(sKey).Add sr ' add the row to the collection
                drCount = drCount + 1 ' count the number of destination rows
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Validate the destination rows count (dictionary count).
    If drCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No valid values in column range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' 5. Using the information in the dictionary, write the grouped values
    '    from the source copy range ('srg') to the destination array.
    
    ' Write the values from the source copy range
    ' to a 2D one-based array ('sData') re-using the variable.
    sData = srg.EntireRow.Columns(sCopyColumns).Value
    ' Write the number of source/destination columns to a variable.
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(sData, 2)
    
    ' Define the destination array ('dData').
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the source array to the destination array.
    
    Dim sItem As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys ' loop through the keys of the dictionary
        For Each sItem In dict(sKey) ' loop through the items of the collection
            dr = dr + 1 ' next destination row
            For c = 1 To cCount ' loop through the source/destination columns
                dData(dr, c) = sData(sItem, c) ' write to the destination array
            Next c
        Next sItem
    Next sKey
    
    ' Free memory since the data is in the destination array.
    Erase sData
    Set dict = Nothing
    
    ' 6. Write the result to the destination worksheet.
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    ' Reference the first row of the destination range.
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, cCount)
        ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
        .Resize(dr).Value = dData
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    End With
    
    ' Save the workbook (decide on your own).
    'wb.Save
    
    ' 7. Inform to not wonder if the code has run or not.
    MsgBox "Discrepency report created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This sorts the data based on the values in the first column. And will run very fast even with a large amount of data. Very nice! If the Employee name is not in the first column, change the line `sKey = sData(sr, 1)` to have the column number for the Employee name.